# Search string in .cs files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, full-text-search

in my Visual studio 2010 i do search for a string and display the find result window.
this is fine but, I need to display 3 lines above and 3 lines below of my target seach. can it be done?

or, Do you know of any tool that will do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is really no way to do this with the Visual Studio search.  It will only display the actual line where the match occurred

Answer (score 1):

I like [Windows Grep](http://www.wingrep.com/) for problems like this one.

UPDATE:

Windows Grep can operate in a "quick" mode that does not apply regular expression matching to the search string.  It also offers limited string-replace functionality.

Comment: we used this (dont like it). thanks. some other people may like it.we need something very simple